# Undefined symbols for architecture arm for

Tags: c++, printf, cs50, getstring

I am new to C++, and trying to use get_string, but I am not sure what I writing wrong that is creating an error.

The code I have is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
   string name = get_string("What's your name? ");
   printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

and it keeps saying the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_get_string", referenced from:
      _main in hello-890d43.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Does any one know what I am doing wrong?

I expected the code take an input and print out hello, (your input).

Comment: Please search this site for `c++ Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`. This question has been asked and answered here several times before. Please **always** do a thorough search of the site before posting a new question.

Comment: Isn't cs50 C rather than C++?

Answer (score 1):

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_get_string", referenced
> from:

Assuming you installed the latest CS50 Library. If not, download it, open the terminal, type `cd`, then hit space, and drag the folder onto the terminal. You should have a file path displaying. Run the "sudo make install" command, type in your Mac password, and the file should install.

Open VSCode and type `clang hello.c -o hello -lcs50`. Once you hit enter type `./hello`.

The code should now run without any errors!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me when trying to use the cs50 **C** library on my local Mac with M1 chip.

Even after installing the library as described here: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/
It still didn't work.

The problem is coming from the fact that the `make` command here doesn't include the link command by default.

Assuming your source file is named `hello.c` instead of just doing:

```
make hello
```

You have to enter the following in your terminal in order to compile:

```
clang hello.c -o hello -lcs50
```

Afterwards, when running the executable, it works as expected:

```
./hello
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make hello LDLIBS="-lcs50"
```

LDLIBS to include the cs50 library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).